# DLLs remains locked after process was kiled

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, dll, handle

I'm trying to automate Windows Service deploying using PowerShell. The step I have problems with is stopping the current version and removing it.

Since it's an CI agent I don't care at all about stopping the service correctly, so I just kill the process with `taskkill /f /im:<exe name>`. Then I try to remove the files and one in about 3 times I get this:

```
Exception: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MirrorService\AWSSDK.dll' is denied.
```

But the DLL is used only by the process I just killed. I tried to catch the exception and log `handle.exe` output. There are no handles for this DLL in the log, and I'm able to remove it.

So, obviously there is a lag between `taskkill` finish its job, and handle releasing. What is the cleanest way to wait for it? Here's what I came up with so far, and none of it looks clean enough to me:

- place a delay (how long?) between `taskkill` and `rm`
- catch the exception and retry `rm` after a pause
- use `handle.exe` / Unlocker to release the DLLs

*PS: I've tried the nicer approach to stopping the service with `stop-service` and `wait-process` and the result was the same*.

**UPD**: putting 300ms delay between stopping the service and removing its files seems to did the trick, but I'm still looking for (1) explanation of the behavior and (2) a more reliable way to ensure dlls are released.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/f`? You are telling the process to be forcefully terminated and not allowing it time to clean up.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the idea. No luck, though: `The process "Much.Stoppy.exe" with PID 10944 could not be terminated.`

Comment: `Stop-Service` does not wait for the service to stop. Did you get the non-terminating error from `Wait-Process`, or did ti claim the process had ended? (I would not be at all surprised if `Wait-Process` returned before the process was gone.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes handles stay open after the service itself reports "STOPPED".  This will check your .dll for any stray handles, if found, it fixes them.

```
$lockedFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\MirrorService\AWSSDK.dll"

GPS|%{$LOCK = $_;$_.Modules|%{If($_.FileName -eq "$lockedFile"){Kill -id $LOCK.id -force}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I would prefer something less hacky, though. Also, I don't look at the service status at all: I either `taskkill` its process or do `stop-service` and then wait for the process to die with `wait-process`.

Comment: You could potentially adapt this into something that waited until the files were unlocked, assuming the process would die eventually.